# Titanium - Determine the cause of application crash

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

For non-crashing error handling, we can use [LogCatcher](https://github.com/dbankier/TiLogCatcher) which will inform us of the corresponding Javascript code which was causing the problem.

However, if an application crashes, then there is obviously no time for the logger to log Javascript errors.

It seems that the only option is to incorporate packages like [ARCA](http://www.acra.ch/) and [testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) to get back the *native* stack trace/crash report etc., which might not be very helpful since in **Titanium** there is a *Javascript*-native translation going on.

Is there any way to determine the cause of application crash even out of such information?

Or is there a way to locate the problematic section of Javascript even in the event of application crash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run application In Debug Mode from titanium SDK, It will help to you find the part of code that creating  a problem.

Comment: It will find corresponding code for non-crashing errors, but not crashing ones, for which it still returns platform native information

Comment: And also what I meant here is I want to catch crashes from the *clients*. Obviously crashes on our own development environments we can catch with relative ease but that doesn't really help a lot.